# sendkeys() not working in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

Till yesterday the below mentioned code was working fine but now i am facing some problem .
The code opens firefox browser then loads facebook.com but the code is not sending 
email and password to web browser i.e. sendkeys() is not working. 
I verified the id of both textbox of email and password which are correct yet code is not working .

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
public class Webdriver2 {

    WebDriver driver ;
    JavascriptExecutor jse;
    public void invokeBrowser()
    {
        try
        {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver-v0.19.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS );


        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
        search();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    public void search()
    {
        try
        {
        driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("example@gmail.com"); 
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("password"); 
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_2")).click();
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        /*driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("spit mumbai");
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(" //button[@aria-label='Search' and @data-testid='facebar_search_button'] ")).click();*/

        }
        catch(InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Webdriver2 w = new Webdriver2();
        w.invokeBrowser();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: code not change and geckodriver not change, i think two possible reason:1)  your firefox upgraded,  2) you need add wait before sendKeys,  you not met this issue before, it's the mail text box display out within 60 seconds (you set page load timeout 30 secs and implicitlyWait 30 secs) at before in most time, but now FaceBook home page become slow or your network become slow.

Comment: Check and see that latest version on driver is being used as per the browser version. This mostly resolves the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try clicking on the two textboxes before you are performing the sendKeys:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("example@gmail.com");
```

The textboxes probably needs focus.

Comment: Take a look at the formatting guidelines when posting an answer. To format text as code, you only need to indent the lines with 4 spaces. The > character is generally used for quotes or sometimes error messages, not code. I fixed the formatting for you so you can take a look at that too.

Answer (score 0):

We need to take care of a couple of things here as follows:

1. The `Email or Phone` field is within an `<input>` tag so we need to take it into account while selecting the locator.
2. The `Password` field is also within an `<input>` tag so we need to take it into account while selecting the locator.
3. If you observe closely the `id` of the `Log In` button is dynamic and also within an `<input>` tag, so we need to consider this factor as well.
4. Here is the minimum sample code block using **`cssSelector`** to access the url `https://www.facebook.com/`, provide `Email or Phone` and `Password`, finally click on `Log In` button:

   ```
   package demo;

   import org.openqa.selenium.By;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

   public class Facebook_Login_CSS_FF {

       public static void main(String[] args) {


           System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
           WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
           driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
           driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input#email")).sendKeys("Ryusei");
           driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='pass']")).sendKeys("Nakamura");
           driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='Log In']")).click();
       }

   }
   ```